# How to tell if (and recover from) a diacetyl rest was done too early?

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature, lager, diacetyl-rest

I've got a lager (Wyeast 2206) that I've just taken out of primary fermentation (at ~8C, for 10 days) for a diacetyl rest (at ~20C).  I picked the time to do it based on "How To Brew" suggesting I wait until bubbling slows to 1-4 bubbles / minute.  It was about 18s between bubbles.

It's now at 20C & is bubbling away furiously, so I'm concerned I may have moved it too early.  How can I tell if it is too early?  Does it matter?  What's the impact and can I recover from it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NEVER** use bubbling as a measure of anything important. You MUST take actual gravity readings to know where your fermentation is.

As a general rule, you should do a diacytl rest when you are about 70-80% done with fermentation. So for a "normal" strength lager (1.050-1.060 OG) I'll start the diacytl rest when the beer hits about the 1.020-1.022 range (assuming I'm expecting it to finish around 1.012-1.014). This is usually around the time when the bubbling starts to slow down a touch, and the krausen starts to droop a bit, but you can't really tell without taking gravity readings. Since lagers ferment a touch slower than ales, the window for the diacytl rest is a bit bigger, and I've never had a lager that dropped too fast so long as I was taking samples every few days.

Flavor wise, if you warmed the lager up too early, you will get some of those undesirable flavors that make Steam Beer (like Anchor Steam) taste like they do. Its hard to describe, but its like a "rough" flavor to me, and you could potentially get a touch of fruity esters as well. However, if your beer started fermentation at the proper temps, and you just warmed it up a touch too early, these flavors should be minimal.

One last thing to remember is basic physics: cold liquids hold more C02 in suspension than warm ones. If you had a beer at, say, 50F and you brought it up to 70F after fermentation was 100% done, **you would see bubbling**. But NOT because of new fermentation, but because of the fact that some of the C02 in suspension at 50F will bubble out at 70F and make your airlock jumpy, just like during fermentation. In fact, this might be exactly what you are experiencing. Your beer might be right at the proper gravity for the d-rest, but the warmer temps ALSO make a few extra bubbles of C02, so it looks like fermentation is going on more vigorously than it actually is.

**tl;dr; - Your beer will most likely be great, but next time, take gravity readings as the fermentation starts slowing, and move to a D-rest temp (63F-70F) when your fermentation is 80% done.**

Comment: This is a very timely answer.  I was planning to start a D-rest on my lager today, but forgot about the 80% gravity.

Comment: Ahh interesting. So I did a gravity reading and from 1.063 I'm now at 1.040 after 24 hours. Should I move it back to the fridge for a bit longer?

Comment: Definitely. If it's still at 1.040 then you'll produce lots of esters at 20C, get it back in the fridge right away. 2-3 Weeks is typical for a lager ferment, and I wouldn't think about moving it before that.

Comment: +1 on "get it back in the fridge right away" if its at 1.040. But -1 on "2-3 Weeks is typical for a lager". I pitch two packets of dry 34/70 into my lagers and hit 80% fermentation within 7-10 days. YMMV. Measure with a hydrometer every few days until you get a feel for your timeline, C4H5As.

Comment: For the record, I just checked mine after 3 days - I'm at 1.024, which is about 65%.  That's 16 gallons with 3 packets of Saflager S-23.  Best part about sampling is drinking it...it's delicious!

Comment: @JoeFish 1.024 and a delicious sample for an under-pitched  S-23 lager on day 3?!? Wow, the beer faeries are much more forgiving at your house than at mine! That would be a sulfur-bomb for me.

Comment: @Graham: 1 packet / 5 gallons is underpitching? Let's see what the website says...80-120 g/hl.  1hl is 26 gals...so for 16 gallons that's...er...50 to 74g.  I pitched 34.5g, so I guess so.  I'll know for next time, but the sample was certainly good enough that I drank the whole thing.  Time will tell how it finishes.

Comment: All this stuff is fundamentally true, but there is an easier way.  Chill the wort to  a few degrees below the desired ferment temp prior to pitching the yeast.  For example, I chill to 48F then pitch my yeast.  I let it sit for 2 days then reset the temp controller to 51F.  Let it go for 2-3 weeks (until the gravity indicates its done) then transfer to a keg and start to lager.  No diacetyl produced, no diacetyl rest needed.  All my lagers are very clean.

Comment: @brewchez that's interesting, as [Denny's answer to my question here](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/7322/1861) suggests **more** diacetyl will be produced at the prolonged low temps.  How long do you typically lager for?

Comment: Denny's point is that after fermentation the yeast clean up faster at higher temps, not that less of it was produced in the first place.  If you start lager yeast fermentation at or below your intended ferment temp, very little diacetyl is produced in the first place.  That little bit is easily cleaned up during a normal 2-3 week ferment at low temps and further more during lagering.  And regarding my lagering phase, it doesn't matter, my beer is diacetyl flavor free before I lager.  I am saying its clean of that at the end of fermentation (at 50F) before I rack to keg and cold crash to lager.